# Exception after adding NSImageCell to NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, tableview

I am trying to add a NSImageCell to a TableView using the following code:

`NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed: @"nvMenuDark.png"];`

`[[self noteAttributeColumnForIdentifier:NoteStarredColumnString] setDataCell: [[[StarredColumnCell alloc] initImageCell: image] autorelease]];`

However, it is throwing the following exception:
`NSImageCell's object value must be an NSImage, not a "__NSCFConstantString".`

StarredColumnCell.h

```
@class NoteObject;

@interface StarredColumnCell : NSImageCell {
    NoteObject *noteObject;

}


- (NoteObject*)noteObject;
- (void)setNoteObject:(NoteObject*)obj;

@end
```

StarredColumnCell.m

```
#import "StarredColumnCell.h"
#import "NotesTableView.h"
#import "NoteObject.h"
#import "GlobalPrefs.h"

@implementation StarredColumnCell

- (id)initImageCell:(NSImage *)image {
    self = [super initImageCell:image];
    self.objectValue = image;
    return self;
}
- (NoteObject*)noteObject {
    return noteObject;
}

- (void)setNoteObject:(NoteObject*)obj {
    [noteObject autorelease];
    noteObject = [obj retain];
}

- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {


}


@end
```

I just would like to have a direction about what could I fix...If I change this cell to NSTextfieldCell it works.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your image being released and the system re-using the memory to store a string.  Try using Instruments to track the retain/release life cycle of the NSImage.

Comment: The datacell is a prototype. Does `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` return a string or an image?

Comment: initImageCell should be initWithImage and NSImageCell doesn't have (super) initImageCell

Comment: @MarekH [initImageCell:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscell/1533898-initimagecell?language=occ) does exist (but isn't the method to use in this case). Is `initWithImage` documented?

Comment: Sry, my Xcode10 had autocomplete bug. My mistake.